# Pass thymeleaf enum field value to DTO enum field

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, thymeleaf, dto

I'm trying to map/save field value from thymeleaf page to DTO object. I have tried in different ways but all i get is null field value in DTO.

I have DTO with enum variable, something like:

```
public SomeDTO{
 private SomeEnum enumTypeVariable;
}
```

and enum

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    VAR1, VAR2;
}
```

and thymeleaf page with hidden input(it's not for editing, just for storing) and enum type variable that is set to one of enum's element

```
<input th:field="${enumTypeVariable}"/>
```

Is there a way to map/save enum value from thymeleaf page to DTO object?

Comment: Please include your controller code (for that view) and the form tag. Are you using th:object in your template file? if yes please make sure to include the html for that too.